# WCF Web Api as a subdomain of an asp.net mvc 3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-web-api

I have an mvc app running on `mydomain.com`, and I have added a wcf web api to the web project.

I can access the rest service by going to `mydomain.com/MyResource` but I actually want `MyResource` to ONLY work if I go to `api.myDomain.com/MyResource`, and `mydomain.com/MyResource` to look for a controller called `MyResourceController` and throw an error if it didn't find it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a new web site in IIS to solve this and create two projects in your solution.